# Interact doesn't work the second time around

Tags: paraview

I'm playing a little with ParaView pvpython, but after closing the interact windows it doesn't open again. Is this correct? How can I do this?

```
➜  ~ /Applications/ParaView-5.7.0.app/Contents/bin/pvpython ; exit;
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from paraview.simple import *
>>> cylinder2 = Cylinder()
>>> cylinder2.Resolution = 6
>>> cylinder2.Height = 1.0
>>> cylinder2.Radius = 0.5
>>> cylinder2.Center = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> cylinder2.Capping = 1
>>> renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
>>> cylinder2Display = Show(cylinder2, renderView1)
>>> Interact()
>>> cylinder2.Resolution = 50
>>> Interact()
```

In mac I don't get any message error, in Windows 10 I get

```
ERROR: In C:\bbd\6519e7fe\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 491
vtkShaderProgram (00000190C6D2E400): Shader object was not initialized, cannot attach it.

Generic Warning: In C:\bbd\6519e7fe\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderTimer.cxx, line 124
vtkOpenGLRenderTimer::Stop called before vtkOpenGLRenderTimer::Start. Ignoring.

ERROR: In C:\bbd\6519e7fe\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 491
vtkShaderProgram (00000190C6D2D320): Shader object was not initialized, cannot attach it.

ERROR: In C:\bbd\6519e7fe\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLVertexArrayObject.cxx, line 280
vtkOpenGLVertexArrayObject (00000190C74323F0): attempt to add attribute without a program for attribute ndCoordIn

Generic Warning: In C:\bbd\6519e7fe\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLQuadHelper.cxx, line 60
Error binding ndCoords to VAO.
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce with the last release instead of using the superbuild ? I cant't reproduce.

Comment: How do you close the first interact window ? I'm not sure it is supposed to be closed. If you want to stop the interaction and continue scripting, press the key `q` when focus on the render window.

Comment: I close with X. If I try to close with `q` the windows doesn't close and it froze instead.

Comment: It is the expected feature of `q`. In pvpython, `Render()` update the view, `Interact()` update the view and let you interact (...) and stop the execution until you press `q`. Between different call to `Render()` or `Interact()` the view stay frozen.  I didn't know it was possible to totally close it ...